# How to share text on Skype using IntentChooser?

Tags: android, android-intent, skype

I need to share the text using intent chooser. I am able to share it on whatsapp,sms,gmail and other apps. But I am not able to share it on skype. When I choose Skype, Skype app is getting opened but text is not copied to the message box. 
I used following code :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Can anybody please help me for this?

Comment: It might, there would no any Component into skype app, which can listen your intent.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Not all third party apps implement expected Intent handling on their end. Skype is one of them. You can exclude skype from chooser or leave it as it is, with a hope they might fix it sometime in a future

Comment: is it documented anywhere, that skype has not handled this intent?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the type to all it works

```
sendIntent.setType("*/*");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." Thus the knowledge base which SO is will really help the future readers.